# Having create fail when id already exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using a rake task to populate my database with some initial data. I want to create a bunch of entries in a table, with the first few IDs, so they're always present, and always have those ids. I don't mind if in a dev environment, someone adds/deletes/modifies records, but I always want the first 5 ids to have values. Here's a simplified version of my lib/tasks/bootstrap.rb file:

```
namespace :bootstrap do
    desc "Create the default problem types"
    task :default_problem_types => :environment do
        ProblemType.create( :id => 1, :name => 'Wrong location', :description => 'blah' )
        ProblemType.create( :id => 2, :name =>  'Wrong name', :description => 'blah' )
        ProblemType.create( :id => 3, :name =>  'Wrong details', :description => 'blah' )
        ProblemType.create( :id => 4, :name =>  'Duplicate', :description => 'blah' )
        ProblemType.create( :id => 5, :name =>  'No longer exists', :description => 'blah' )
    end

    desc "Run all bootstrapping tasks"
    task :all => [:default_problem_types]
end
```

This works fine on an empty database. It creates 5 new entries in the problem_types table:

```
1 - Wrong Location 
2 - Wrong name 
3 - Wrong details 
4 - Duplicate 
5 - No longer exists
```

The problem is that if I run it a second time, it creates 5 new records, with IDs 6, 7, 8, 9, 10. That's despite the fact that I provided ids to the create() call that already exist. I'm expecting those calls to fail, because if I try to do the following SQL:

```
insert into problem_types (id, name, description) values (1, 'foo', 'bar');
```

... it fails:

ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

How do I get the create() method to fail if the ID already exists?

Thanks.

Comment: why are you using rake task instead of seeds? With seeds, if you correctly clean your DB, you can always have ids of 1-5

Comment: I was using a rake task because I came across another post recommending that, and I wasn't familiar with seeds. However, after reading your comment, I looked up seeds, and think that seeds are more appropriate.

Comment: I'm switching to seeds, but when I do ProblemType.delete_all, then re-create them, (using ProblemType.find_or_initialize_by_name()) the IDs do not start at 1-5; they keep incrementing. (I'm using mySQL locally). Is there another way to correctly clean the DB?

Comment: there is gem, called database_cleaner, use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dynamic `find_or_create_by` or `find_or_initialize_by` method. You can read more about these in the [Rails guides for the Active Record query interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html). They allows you to write something like this for each `ProblemType` without creating duplicates by name:

```
problem_type = ProblemType.find_or_initialize_by_name('Wrong location')
problem_type.description = "blah"
problem_type.save
```

I agree with @benchwarmer; it's best to avoid managing the primary key yourself. If you must have a numerical identifier that some semantic value, try adding a separate column and set that value accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Rule of thumb: You dont assign ID on your own. Let database do its work. If you want your problem names to be unique then you can add `validates_uniqueness_of :name` into model file and the records won't be created if the same name exists

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't so concerned about having the IDs be 1-5 as I was not having duplicates. @rossta's suggestion of using the name (find_or_initialize_by_name) did the trick.